# Installing Kubernetes on mac with vagrant and virtualbox

Tags: macos, vagrant, virtualbox, kubernetes

This is my first attempt to install and use Kubernetes. I am trying to install an environment on Mac for developing my own apps and deploying them for test locally with Kubernetes. I am familiar with using Vagrant, VirtualBox and Docker for the same purpose. When I saw this page https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/getting-started-guides/vagrant.md I assumed it would be trivial. I executed these lines:

```
export KUBERNETES_PROVIDER=vagrant
curl -sS https://get.k8s.io | bash
```

This created a master VM and a Minion, but Kubernetes seems to have failed to start on the master. On the master /var/log/salt/master is full of python Traceback errors, like this:

```
2015-07-17 22:14:42,629 [cherrypy.error   ][INFO    ][3252] [17/Jul/2015:22:14:42] ENGINE Started monitor thread '_TimeoutMonitor'.
2015-07-17 22:14:42,736 [cherrypy.error   ][ERROR   ][3252] [17/Jul/2015:22:14:42] ENGINE Error in HTTP server: shutting down
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cherrypy/process/servers.py", line 187, in _start_http_thread
self.httpserver.start()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cherrypy/wsgiserver/wsgiserver2.py", line 1824, in start
    raise socket.error(msg)
error: No socket could be created
```

Vagrant is version 1.7.3. VirtualBox is version 4.3.30

Have I made an obvious stupid mistake?

Comment: I am having exactly this same problem, also. One difference: I am using the old VirtualBox version, 4.3.28, as recommended in the instructions. My vagrant is 1.7.4, on Mac OS 10.10.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't yet know the fix but I know what is going wrong since it happens to me as well:

- OS X 10.10.3
- Vagrant 1.7.4
- VirtualBox 4.3.30
- Kubernetes 1.0.1

When I run the default configuration of this (which creates one "master" and one "minion" VM) I see that the static IP address is not being assigned to the "eth1" interface, and I also see that the Salt API server is sitting in what appears to be an infinite retry loop because it is trying to listen on that IP address.

Also, the following message happened during boot:

```
[vagrant@kubernetes-master ~]$ dmesg | grep eth1
[    9.321496] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth1: link is not ready
```

So basically, the static IP address didn't get assigned because eth1 wasn't ready when the system first booted, and Salt is waiting for it to get assigned.

I could fix this after boot by sshing to the box using "vagrant ssh" and running the command:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/network restart
```

on each host.

This "fixes" eth1 by assigning the static IP address, and after that Salt begins to do its thing, installs Docker, boots various containers, and so on.

What I don't know is how to make this work every time without manual intervention. It appears to be some sort of a race condition between Vagrant and VirtualBox.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to kick the tires with Kubernetes, I'd recommend installing [boot2docker](http://boot2docker.io) and then following the [Running kubernetes locally via Docker](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/release-1.0/docs/getting-started-guides/docker.md) getting started guide. Once you are comfortable interacting with the Kubernetes API and want a more complex local setup, you can then work on installing Vagrant.

If the Vagrant instructions aren't working, you should also feel free to file a bug in the github repository.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial pointed by Robert is realy easy to run. Just change the version to 0.21.2 (maybe 0.21.3 works too).

Else, if you prefer a vagrant solution, try with [pires](https://github.com/pires/kubernetes-vagrant-coreos-cluster) cluster on vagrant. It runs with almost nothing to change.

Answer (score 0):

Running **Kubernetes inside VirtualBox** requires 4 networks and some adjustments to the configuration:

[image: Kubernetes inside VirtualBox Network Overview]

- The VirtualBox `HOST ONLY` network will be the network used to access the Kubernetes master and nodes from the Mac or PC.
- The `NAT Network` to download packages from the Internet.
- The internal connections between Kubernetes `PODs` uses a tunnel network `TUN`
- The `Kubernetes Cluster IP Network` is a private IP range used inside the cluster to give each Kubernetes service a dedicated IP
- Vagrantfile needs to pass the node public IPs to the Ansible roles that configure Kubernetes to set `KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS` environment variable with the public IP of each node (required for reading logs using kubectl).
- `NodePort` needs to be used to publish applications running inside the Kubernetes cluster as Load Balancers are not available in VirtualBox.

See the full example and download the code at [Building a Kubernetes Cluster with Vagrant and Ansible (without Minikube)](https://www.itwonderlab.com/ansible-kubernetes-vagrant-tutorial/), it has been tested in Ubuntu but should work on a MAC as well.